# How do I get the coefficients of my mean equation when using sGARCH?

Tags: r, coefficients

I hope someone can help me with the following basic question regarding GARCH in R:

Trying to find out whether there is a day-of-the-week effect in some indices I have done the following OLS in R:

= Φ1 +Φ2*2 +Φ3*3 +Φ4*D4 +Φ5*D5 +ΦR−1 + (Where Φ are the coefficients and D are Dummys that turn 1 or 0)

Code:

```
omxlm <- lm(Return ~ Weekday + ReturnLag + DAX, data = omx)
```

Because of heteroskedasticity I extent my study using GARCH modeling.

Using "rugarch":

```
ug_spec = ugarchspec(mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,0)))
ugfit = ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec, data = omx)
```

I only receive mean and parameters regarding the volatility equation

```
        Estimate
mu      0.000535    
ar1    -0.044467    
omega   0.000001    
alpha1  0.080284    
beta1   0.913962
```

Where do I find the Estimations for my mean equation (e.g. Φ1, Φ2, Φ3, Φ4, Φ5) after using the GARCH?

How can I Incorporate the above OLS-Regression to GARCH-model in order to receive fitted coefficients?

Comment: please post a code of what you've tried already.

Comment: please edit your original question and add the code there. it will then have a much higher chance of getting you the answers you seek.

Comment: Perhaps better asked at https://quant.stackexchange.com/